# Is there is an algorithm to make sure that every node in a graph has a path to any other node in that graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory

I was writing a code to make sure that a graph is connected, which means that you can reach any node form any other node in the graph. But my code is taking a long time to run. What is the fastest algorithm to implement this?

Comment: what type of graph? directed? or undirected?

Comment: @M.Khooryani undirected

Comment: what is your algorithm? run dfs on a vertex, then all vertices should be visited, time complexity: O(V+E)

Comment: I don't know any algorithm by name, but they're [rather simple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_(graph_theory)#Computational_aspects)

Comment: Please post the code that you are having problems with.

Comment: Read also: [Connected component algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)).

Answer (score 3):

If it's an undirected graph, then:

1. Pick any node and do a traversal (depth-first or breadth-first doesn't really matter), putting each node visited into a dictionary or map.
2. Compare your list of nodes against that dictionary. Both structures should contain the same nodes.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the size of your graph.

As @Mehdi noted in the comment, you should definitely have a look at 'Strongly Connected Components' concept which says two node `a` and `b` are in same component if and only if there is at least a path from `a` to `b` and also there is a path from `b` to `a`.

This method works excellent in case of having large graph (like 1M nodes).

[image: SCC in D-Graph]

There are many codes that do compute strongly connected components of a graph. I faced exactly same issue and found the solution with that concept (link to [github issue](https://github.com/wo80/CSparse.NET/issues/17))

What you should do is to find strongly connected components (SCC)s in your graph, then if there is only one of them then all your nodes are connected, if there is more than one, then there are some nodes that are connected in one directional (e.g you cannot leave their component in any way)